# Nested classes In Html, Css styling Of innermost class

Tags: html, css

if there are 3-4 nested classes in HTML, what is the best way to mention the innermost class while styling in CSS.

```
<div class="head">
<form class="newmem">
<input type="text" name"Firstname" value="First Name">
<a class="SignUp" href="some link"> Sign up</a>
</form>
```

Now when I want to style the sign up button what should I write in css, do I have to mention ".head  signUp" or do I have to write ".head newmem signup"

Comment: Please share your code. This should be simple to do with CSS and classes.

Comment: Basically, you should brush up on your CSS selectors. Learn about descendant and child selectors, and importantly the difference between them. Then look at the sibling selector options. Also be aware an element can have more than one class. E.g `<a class="classA classB">` has two classes that can be styled individually or together. Also be aware you can also select on attributes. Finally, but importantly, learn about [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: any good online source that you can suggest. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mention the parent class. You can access the child class directly.

In the case you have two forms, say `class="newmem"` and another `class="oldmem"`, and both have `<a class="SignUp" href="some link"> Sign up</a>`, and you want to make changes to the other one without `id` you can do: `.oldmem .SignUp { }` and only the one under the parent you mentioned is affected.

Answer (score 0):

By saying .classname
(classname is whatever your class is named.)
It doesn't matter if it is nested, it is still referenced like any other element.

Comment: Thanks, What if There are a bunch of inputs and I want to style them indivisually, do I have to class them , and what is the name in the input written for

Comment: well to style them individually, you could assign an `id` to them

Comment: so, I would do something like this: `<div id="whatever it is"></div>`

Comment: hit the check mark button to show that I'm correct. If my answer was correct.

Comment: Styling by id is not necessary here. Lets say you have a first name and last name field,  you want them to have some similarities but one point of difference. You could then use a modifier class to make the point of differnce. E.g `<input name="fName" class="names first" /><inpur name="lName" class="names last"/>` You can now provide common styling with `.names` and individually with `.names.first` and/or `.last`